# How do you render a partial depending on a date and/or time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, render, partial

I'm working in Rails3 and I would like to render a partial depending on a specific date/time.  For example, on Christmas I want to show the Christmas content, on Halloween the Halloween content, etc.  It would be great if the partials were stored in a datastore somewhere and called out depending on some metadata.

I can do this in a one-by-one type of way but I wanted to know if anyone knew of a Gem that may already do something like this.  I'm fairly certain that I'm not the first person to want to render code depending on a date/time.  However, if there are no ready made solutions, do you have any clues as to how to architect a mechanism to allow "content-owners" to maintain these partials without programmer involvement?

Answer (score 0):

I would have a table with a 'date_start' and 'content' fields.

In the controller, I would select the first record where 'start_date' is less than or equal to the current date and then render that content.  See the code below (untested, but you should get the gist).

in controller:

@record = Table.where('start_date <= curdate()'.order('start_date desc').limit(1)

in view

<%= RedCloth.new(@record.content).to_html.html_safe %>

That should get you started, let me know if you need more information.  Once you refactor, you could put the code from the controller in a model and use scopes.